# C# style Event and Delegate in C++

Tags: c++, template, event-handling

I'd appreciate advice regarding both the implementation detail and ways to improve usage/performance/generic.

There are two parts: `XDelegate`, which is I got from [here](http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/), and `XEvent`, which is the event implementation similar to C#.

```
#pragma once
#include <unordered_map>
//hashing function
//TODO: replace hashing with something else if it's too expensive
template<typename return_type, typename... params>
class XDelegate;
namespace std {
    template<typename return_type, typename... params>
    struct hash<XDelegate<return_type, params ...>> {
        typedef return_type(*Type)(void* callee, params...);

        static size_t hash_combine(size_t seed, size_t v)
        {
            return seed ^= v + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
        }
        size_t operator()(const XDelegate<return_type, params ...> &pDelegate) const
        {
            size_t a = std::hash<void*>{}(pDelegate.fpCallee);
            size_t b = std::hash<Type>{}(pDelegate.fpCallbackFunction);
            return hash_combine(a, b);
        }
    };
};

//nice generic variadic delegate from http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/
template<typename return_type, typename... params>
class XDelegate
{
    friend struct std::hash<XDelegate>;

    typedef return_type(*Type)(void* callee, params...);
public:
    XDelegate(void* callee, Type function)
        : _fpCallee(callee)
        , _fpCallbackFunction(function) {}
    template <class T, return_type(T::*TMethod)(params...)>
    static XDelegate from_function(T* callee)
    {
        XDelegate d(callee, &methodCaller<T, TMethod>);
        return d;
    }
    return_type operator()(params... xs) const
    {
        return (*_fpCallbackFunction)(_fpCallee, xs...);
    }
private:
    void* _fpCallee;
    Type _fpCallbackFunction;
    template <class T, return_type(T::*TMethod)(params...)>
    static return_type methodCaller(void* callee, params... xs)
    {
        T* p = static_cast<T*>(callee);
        return (p->*TMethod)(xs...);
    }
};


//C# style delegate-event for none ref class.
template<typename return_type, typename... params>
class XEvent
{
    friend struct std::hash<XDelegate<return_type, params ...>>;

public:
    size_t add(XDelegate<return_type, params ...> pDelegate)
    {
        size_t token = std::hash<XDelegate<return_type, params ...>>{}(pDelegate);
        auto result = _delegates.insert_or_assign(token, pDelegate);
#ifdef _DEBUG
        //if assignment took place, ie) there is a hash collision, throw exception.
        if (!result.second)
        {
            throw std::exception("XEvent hash collision");
        }
#endif
        return token;
    }
    void remove(size_t pToken)
    {
        _delegates.erase(pToken);
    }
    size_t size() const
    {
        return _delegates.size();
    }
    //on hindsight, I don't think C# events have return value?
    std::unordered_map<size_t, return_type> operator()(params... xs)const
    {
        std::unordered_map<size_t, return_type> result;
        for (auto itr = _delegates.begin(); itr != _delegates.end(); ++itr)
        {
            result[itr->first] = itr->second(xs...);

        }
        //return map of event tokens mapped to the results.
        return result;
    }
private:


    std::unordered_map<size_t, XDelegate<return_type, params ...>> _delegates;
};


template<typename... params>
class XEvent<void, params ...>
{
    friend struct std::hash<XDelegate<void, params ...>>;

public:
    size_t add(XDelegate<void, params ...> pDelegate)
    {
        size_t token = std::hash<XDelegate<void, params ...>>{}(pDelegate);
        auto result = _delegates.insert_or_assign(token, pDelegate);
#ifdef _DEBUG
        //if assignment took place, ie) there is a hash collision, throw exception.
        if (!result.second)
        {
            throw std::exception("XEvent hash collision");
        }
#endif
        return token;
    }
    void remove(size_t pToken)
    {
        _delegates.erase(pToken);
    }
    size_t size() const
    {
        return _delegates.size();
    }
    void operator()(params... xs)const
    {
        for (auto itr = _delegates.begin(); itr != _delegates.end(); ++itr)
        {
            itr->second(xs...);
        }
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<size_t, XDelegate<void, params ...>> _delegates;
};
```

It is used like this:

```
_returnEventTokens.push_back(_returnEvent.add(XDelegate<int, std::wstring>::from_function<EventTester, &EventTester::returnEventCallback1>(_tester)));
_returnEventTokens.push_back(_returnEvent.add(XDelegate<int, std::wstring>::from_function<EventTester, &EventTester::returnEventCallback2>(_tester)));
_returnEventTokens.push_back(_returnEvent.add(XDelegate<int, std::wstring>::from_function<EventTester, &EventTester::returnEventCallback3>(_tester)));


_returnEvent(L"Return event called!\n");

for (auto itr = _noReturnEventTokens.begin(); itr != _noReturnEventTokens.end(); ++itr)
{
    _noReturnEvent.remove(*itr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of "it is used like this" leaves quite a bit to the imagination. For example, what are the types of `_noReturnEventTokens`, `_returnEventTokens`, and `_returnEvent`? How are they declared? What do you expect to *happen* when you evaluate `_returnEvent(L"Return event called!\n")`?

---

I don't think the code is so "unpleasant" to read as CodeGorilla suggested; but it could definitely be improved by some minor reformatting. I strongly suggest putting a blank line between each pair of member function definitions: that is, not

```
auto f()
{
}
auto g()
{
}
```

but instead

```
auto f()
{
}

auto g()
{
}
```

. This is minor but would help quite a bit in "breaking up" the code visually. If you want to get the vertical real-estate back, then cuddle your braces:

```
auto f() {
}

auto g() {
}
```

---

```
void operator()(params... xs)const
{
    for (auto itr = _delegates.begin(); itr != _delegates.end(); ++itr)
    {
        itr->second(xs...);
    }
}
```

The first thing to notice about this code is that it contains an old-style (non-range) `for` loop. Rewrite it as

```
    for (auto&& pair : _delegates) {
        pair.second(xs...);
    }
```

The second thing that caught my eye was the construct `params... xs`. Taking a parameter pack *by value* is rare; taking by perfect-forward (`params&&... xs`) is more common. But because you're doing a lot of metaprogramming here, maybe by-value is correct. So I kept looking to find out where `params` came from — and I *think* all your uses are reasonable. There was one place I thought you should have been using perfect-forwarding, but then I realized that you probably did need to avoid moving-out-of the arguments prematurely (because they would be used again by other delegates).

Incidentally, I recommend `CamelCase` for template parameters. What you called `params...`, I would have called `Args...` or possibly just `Ts...`.

---

```
namespace std {
    template<typename return_type, typename... params>
    struct hash<XDelegate<return_type, params ...>> {
        typedef return_type(*Type)(void* callee, params...);

        static size_t hash_combine(size_t seed, size_t v)
        {
            return seed ^= v + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
        }
        size_t operator()(const XDelegate<return_type, params ...> &pDelegate) const
        {
            size_t a = std::hash<void*>{}(pDelegate.fpCallee);
            size_t b = std::hash<Type>{}(pDelegate.fpCallbackFunction);
            return hash_combine(a, b);
        }
    };
};
```

That last `};` should be just `}`, and I strongly recommend adding the comment `// namespace std` for readability. You'll see this "end-of-namespace comment" convention being used in most C++ codebases these days.

But for a simple specialization of `std::hash`, you actually don't need to reopen the namespace — you can just specialize the qualified `struct std::hash`, like this:

```
template<class R, class... Args>
struct std::hash<XDelegate<R, Args...>> {
    static size_t hash_combine(size_t seed, size_t v) {
        seed ^= v + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
        return seed;
    }

    size_t operator()(const XDelegate<R, Args...>& pDelegate) const {
        using Type = R(void *, Args...);
        size_t a = std::hash<void*>{}(pDelegate.fpCallee);
        size_t b = std::hash<Type*>{}(pDelegate.fpCallbackFunction);
        return hash_combine(a, b);
    }
};
```

Observe the cuddling of braces, the blank line between function definitions, the CamelCase template parameter names (and much shorter — `return_type` becomes `R`), and the modernized `using T = U` in place of `typedef U T`.

Observe that instead of declaring `Type` as an alias for a function-pointer type, I declared it as a function type and moved the `*` down into the place it was used, in `std::hash<Type*>`, which makes the two `std::hash<X*>` invocations nicely symmetrical.

Observe that I never put two side-effects on the same source line of code. Instead of `return seed ^= expr;`, I write `seed ^= expr;` and then on the next line `return` (the new value of) `seed`. This *really* matters when you start getting into atomic/lock-free stuff, but it never hurts.

---

```
friend struct std::hash<XDelegate>;
```

Consider giving `XDelegate` a non-static *member* function `hash()`, so that if you want the hash of an object `x` you just say `x.hash()`, instead of `std::hash<decltype(x)>{}(x)`. You'd still have to provide a trivial out-of-line specialization

```
template<class R, class... Args>
struct std::hash<XDelegate<R, Args...>> {
    size_t operator()(const XDelegate<R, Args...>& x) const {
        return x.hash();
    }
};
```

but it would no longer need to be a `friend` of the class.

---

I'm sure there's more event-and-delegate-relevant kinds of things to talk about, but this is where I'll stop. :)

Comment: "Consider giving XDelegate a non-static member function hash()" ,I had a facepalm moment with that. I automatically added the std::hash specialization when I'm not using it for std::unordered_map key, heh.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not very pleasant to read, its like it has been autogenerated.  I wouldn't like to have to pick up from you and fix a bug in it.  It may be a very clever way of doing whatever it is you are trying to do, but I don't think its good code.

It has very little in the way of meaningful comments, nothing to describe what the purpose of the templates and functions are.  If you combine this with the links to websites in my experience it implies that the person writing it doesn't really understand what the code does.

Why do you only throw exceptions in DEBUG builds, does the code never go wrong in RELEASE builds?

One question I can't get out of my head is if you want C# delegates and events why not program in C#, otherwise just use what is already in C++?